# Multi-level expand in SAP rest API Service Layer

Tags: sapb1

I'm trying to get the Batches per ItemGroups. Is it possible to expand the ItemGroups in Item that is expanded from BatchNumberDetails?

`BatchNumberDetails?$expand=Item($expand=ItemGroups)`

What i want to achieve is like the code above.

To expand multi-level in SAP Service Layer API